# Derivatives without simplifing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the derivative of the following function (do not simplify your answer): $\dfrac{4x^2-8x+14}{x^7-6x^3+4x-9} $ Do I use the quotient rule?

Comment: Yes, since it is a quotient, the quotient rule seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use the quotinet rule
$\frac{(8x-8)(x^7-6x^3+4x-9)-(4x^2-8x+14)(7x^6-18x^2+4)}{(x^7-6x^3+4x-9)^2}$